# python showing ()'s around print command

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

When ever i try to run this script through the terminal on my raspberry pi:

```
input = 5

num = int(input)

for i in range(2,num):
if (num % i) == 0:
    print(num, "is divisible by", i)
    break
else:
    print(num, "is a prime number")
    break
```

its output is:

```
(5, 'is a prime number')
```

i cannot find any reason that this would be happening and it only happens through the terminal, but for some reason if i take away the ()'s it still works, which it shouldn't i am very new at python and may have made a silly mistake but i can't find anything about it online

Comment: is it possible you're running python-2.x ?

Comment: can u check in your terminal `python --version`

Comment: It's not merely possible, it's guaranteed. You're using Python 2.x. `print` is a statement, and you don't need the parentheses. Using parentheses means you're printing a tuple, which explains why it's being printed the way it's being printed. If you don't mean to be using Python 2.x, sort that out first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using python3 before my command fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `format` with `print`

`print("{0} is divisible by {1}".format(num, i))`